# How to draw Shape for Card in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a card with text in the form of a dialog. But I need to add a pop-up effect in the form of a tail in the lower right corner as in the example in the picture.

[image]

And I don't quite understand how this can be implemented. I wrote the code for the card from the second picture without any problems, but I don't quite understand how to add an additional element. Can you tell me in which direction to move?

```
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .defaultMinSize(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.min_card_height)),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, dialogBorderStrokeColor)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp, 12.dp),
            text = text
        )
    }
```

Comment: Use path https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42

Answer (score 1):

For a custom shape you should use a [path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path). Here is an example of a right side dialog bubble. Note the additional text padding on the right.

[image]

**Path**

```
fun Path.rightBubbleShape(
    size: Size,
    cornerRadius: Float,
    tailWidth: Float,
) {
    val arcBoxSize = cornerRadius * 2
    moveTo(size.width, size.height)
    // bottom left
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f,
            top = size.height - arcBoxSize,
            right = arcBoxSize,
            bottom = size.height,
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 90f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    // top left
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f,
            top = 0f,
            right = arcBoxSize,
            bottom = arcBoxSize,
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 180f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    // top right
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - arcBoxSize - tailWidth,
            top = 0f,
            right = size.width - tailWidth,
            bottom = arcBoxSize,
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 270f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    // bottom right
    cubicTo(
        x1 = size.width - tailWidth,
        y1 = size.height - cornerRadius,
        x2 = size.width - tailWidth,
        y2 = size.height,
        x3 = size.width,
        y3 = size.height,
    )
    close()
}
```

**Usage**

```
        val cornerRadius = 20.dp
        val tailWidth = 15.dp
        val rightBubblePadding = PaddingValues(
            start = 20.dp,
            end = 20.dp + tailWidth,
            top = 12.dp,
            bottom = 12.dp,
        )
        val (radius, tail) = with(LocalDensity.current) {
            listOf(cornerRadius.toPx(), tailWidth.toPx())
        }
        val rightBubble = remember {
            GenericShape { size, _ ->
                this.rightBubbleShape(
                    size = size,
                    cornerRadius = radius,
                    tailWidth = tail,
                )
            }
        }
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.min_card_height)),
            shape = rightBubble,
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, dialogBorderStrokeColor),
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(rightBubblePadding),
                text = text,
            )
        }
```

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you so much, kind man! Health to you and your loved ones!